# How to prove that for index i all the following n sums are positive?

Tags: induction

Given are $n$ real numbers $x(1)$, $x(2)$, ..., $x(n)$. Some of
them are positive, some may be negative. The total sum
is positive.   Prove the following statement:

There exists some index $i$ such that all the following
$n$ sums are positive:

$$x(i)$$
$$x(i) + x(i+1)$$
$$x(i) + x(i+1) + x(i+2)$$
$$...$$
$$x(i) + x(i+1) + x(i+2) + ... + x(i+n-1)$$
Here "plus" and "minus" within the brackets are meant modulo $n$.

Answer (score 2):

For $0\le i\le n$, let $s(i)=x(1)+\cdots +x(i)$ (so in particular $s(0)=0$ and $s(n)>0$).
Let $$m=\min\{s(0),s(1),\ldots,s(n)\} $$
and let $\iota$ be maximal with $0\le\iota\le n$ and $s(\iota)=m$.
As $s(0)=0<s(n)$, it is clear that $m\le 0$ and $\iota<n$.
Thus for $i:=\iota+1$ we have $1\le i\le n$, as desired.
Then for $1\le j<i$, we find 
$$x(i)+\cdots+x(n)+x(1)+\cdots + x(j)=s(n)-s(\iota)+s(j)\ge s(n)>0$$
and for $i\le j\le n$, we have $s(j)>m$ and hence
$$x(i)+\cdots+ x(j)=s(j)-s(\iota)>0.$$

Comment: Hello Hagen. Thanks for your response, but i have a question! 
i understand that you supposed a maximal value ι where m is minimum, but i cannot understand "what is J?" what does it refer to?
THanks for your time!